# Using python's OpenGL API, how do I perform glDrawElements on a subset of the element index array?

Tags: python, opengl

I am trying to become familiar with python's OpenGL API and I have reached the point where I can texture quads.  Now I want to put different textures on different quads, so I need to be able to render a subset of the quad elements, change the texture, and then render the rest of the quads.

```
# based on http://www.pygame.org/wiki/GLSLExample


import sys

import pygame

import OpenGL.GL as gl
import OpenGL.GLU as glu
import OpenGL.GLUT as glut
from OpenGL.arrays import vbo
import numpy
from math import *
from PIL import Image


def compile_shader(source, shader_type):
    shader = gl.glCreateShader(shader_type)
    #source = c_char_p(source)
    length = -1 #c_int(-1)
    gl.glShaderSource(shader, source)
    gl.glCompileShader(shader)

    status = gl.glGetShaderiv(shader, gl.GL_COMPILE_STATUS)
    if not status:
        print_log(shader)
        gl.glDeleteShader(shader)
        raise ValueError( 'Shader compilation failed' )
    return shader


def compile_program(vertex_source, fragment_source):
    vertex_shader = None
    fragment_shader = None
    program = gl.glCreateProgram()

    if vertex_source:
        vertex_shader = compile_shader(vertex_source, gl.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        gl.glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader)
    if fragment_source:
        fragment_shader = compile_shader(fragment_source, gl.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        gl.glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader)

    gl.glLinkProgram(program)

    if vertex_shader:
        gl.glDeleteShader(vertex_shader)
    if fragment_shader:
        gl.glDeleteShader(fragment_shader)

    return program


def load_texture(file_name):
    image  = Image.open(file_name)
    width  = image.size[0]
    height = image.size[1]
    image_bytes  = image.convert("RGBA").tobytes ( "raw", "RGBA", 0, -1)
    texture = gl.glGenTextures(1)

    gl.glBindTexture     ( gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture )
    gl.glTexParameterf   ( gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.GL_REPEAT )
    gl.glTexParameterf   ( gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.GL_REPEAT )
    gl.glTexParameteri   ( gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.GL_NEAREST )
    gl.glTexParameteri   ( gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR )


    glu.gluBuild2DMipmaps ( gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_RGBA, width, height, gl.GL_RGBA, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_bytes )

    return texture

def perspective_matrix(fov, aspect_, near, far):
    # https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/166405-Perspective-Matrix-implementation

    f = 1/tan(fov/2)
    #print(f, fov)
    wiggy = -2 * far * near / (far - near)
    aspect = aspect_
    return numpy.matrix( [
                             [ f/aspect, 0, 0, 0],
                             [0, f, 0, 0],
                             [0, 0, (far+near)/(near-far), wiggy],
                             [0, 0, -1, 0]] , dtype=numpy.float32)


def print_log(shader):

    length = gl.glGetShaderiv(shader, gl.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH)

    if length > 0:

        log = gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader)
        print(log, file=sys.stderr)

#
#
#

def translation_matrix(x, y, z):
    return numpy.matrix([[1, 0, 0, x],
                         [0, 1, 0, y],
                         [0, 0, 1, z],
                         [0, 0, 0, 1]], numpy.float32)


def scale_matrix(scale):
    return numpy.array([[scale, 0, 0, 0],
                        [0, scale, 0, 0],
                        [0, 0, scale, 0],
                        [0, 0, 0, 1]], numpy.float32)


def norm4( mat):
    return [mat, mat / mat[0,3] ]


def rotation_matrix(radians, axis):
    len = sqrt( axis[0]*axis[0] + axis[1]*axis[1] + axis[2]*axis[2])
    x = axis[0]/len
    y = axis[1]/len
    z = axis[2]/len

    c = cos(radians)
    s = sin(radians)
    t=1-c

    # http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/angleToMatrix/
    return numpy.matrix( [[ t*x*x + c, t*x*y - z*s, t*x*z + y*s, 0],
                          [ t*x*y + z*s, t*y*y + c, t*y*z - x*s, 0],
                          [ t*x*z - y*s, t*y*z + x*s, t*z*z + c, 0],
                          [0,0,0,1]], dtype=numpy.float32)


def attributes( handle ):
    # http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40p%40y%40PyGLy-HEAD%40pygly%40shader.py/210/OpenGL.GL.glGetActiveAttrib/python
    """Returns an iterator for the attributes of the specified program.

    Each attribute returns a tuple.

    :rtype: (name, size, type)
    :return: A tuple consisting of 3 values:
        name is the variable name
        size is the variable size in bytes
        type is the GL enumeration
    """
    # get number of active uniforms
    num_attributes = gl.glGetProgramiv( handle, gl.GL_ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES )

    for index in range( num_attributes ):
        yield attribute_for_index( handle, index )

def attribute_for_index( handle, index ):
    """Returns the attribute for the specified attribute index.

    :rtype: tuple(name, size, type)
    """
    # Constants like GLsizei are only found in OpenGL.constants
    # for older versions of pyopengl
    name_length = 30
    glNameSize = (gl.constants.GLsizei)()
    glSize = (gl.constants.GLint)()
    glType = (gl.constants.GLenum)()
    glName = (gl.constants.GLchar * name_length)()

    gl.glGetActiveAttrib(
        handle,
        index,
        name_length,
        glNameSize,
        glSize,
        glType,
        glName
        )

    name, size, type = glName.value, glSize.value, glType.value
    return name, size, type


def app():
    glut.glutInit(sys.argv)
    width, height = 640, 480
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.OPENGL | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

    program = compile_program('''
    // Vertex program
    attribute vec2 vertex_uv;
    uniform mat4 mvp;
    varying vec3 pos;
    varying vec2 texCoord;
    void main() {
        pos = gl_Vertex.xyz;
        gl_Position = mvp * gl_Vertex;
        texCoord = vertex_uv;
    }
    ''', '''
    // Fragment program
    varying vec3 pos;
    varying vec2 texCoord;
    uniform sampler2D tex;
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor.rgb = texture(tex, texCoord);
        //gl_FragColor.r = 0.5;
    }
    ''')

    persp =perspective_matrix(pi/4, 1024/float(768), 0.01, 1000)


    mat_loc = gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, bytes("mvp", "ascii"))
    print(mat_loc)
    uv_loc = gl.glGetAttribLocation(program, bytes("vertex_uv", "ascii"))
    print(uv_loc)
    tmp = gl.glGetAttribLocation(program, bytes("gl_Vertex", "ascii"))
    print([ "gl_Vertex", tmp] )

    tex_loc = gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, bytes("tex", "ascii"))
    print(["tex uniform location", tex_loc])

    if False:
        name_length = 30
        glNameSize = (gl.constants.GLsizei)()
        glSize = (gl.constants.GLint)()
        glType = (gl.constants.GLenum)()
        glName = (gl.constants.GLchar * name_length)()
        gl.glGetActiveAttrib(program,1,
                             name_length,
                             glNameSize,
                             glSize,
                             glType,
                             glName)
        print(glName.value)

        for name,y,z in attributes(program):
            print([name,y,z, gl.glGetAttribLocation(program, name)])


    gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)


    vertices = [-1, -1, -1,
                1, -1, -1,
                1, 1, -1,
                -1, 1, -1,

                -1, -1, 1,
                1, -1, 1,
                1, 1, 1,
                -1, 1, 1]
    uvs = [0,0,
           1,0,
           1,1,
           0,1,

           0,0,
           1,0,
           1,1,
           0,1,

           ]
    indices = [0,1,2,3,
               4,5,6,7,
#               8,9,10,11,
#               12,13,14,15,
#               16,17,18,19,
#               20,21,22,23
    ]

    vert_buffer = vbo.VBO(numpy.array(vertices, dtype=numpy.float32))
    uv_buffer = vbo.VBO(numpy.array(uvs, dtype=numpy.float32))
    index_buffer = vbo.VBO(numpy.array(indices, dtype=numpy.uint16), target=gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER)

    #

    texture1 = load_texture("bear64.png")
    texture2 = load_texture("flamingo64.gif")

    #

    quit = False
    angle = 0

    gl.glUseProgram(program)

    # bind all our buffers out here because this scene is so static
    index_buffer.bind()
    vert_buffer.bind()
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.GL_FLOAT, False, 0, None)

    if uv_loc>=0:
        uv_buffer.bind()
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(uv_loc)
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(uv_loc, 2, gl.GL_FLOAT, False, 0, None)

    import time
    while not quit:
        t0 = time.time()
        for e in pygame.event.get():

            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit=True
            elif e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                print(e.key)
                if e.key == pygame.K_q:
                    quit = True


        gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        z = (t0/10)%1

        mvp =  persp*translation_matrix(0,0,-5)* scale_matrix(1) * rotation_matrix(pi*0.4, [-1,0,0]) *rotation_matrix(z*pi*2, [0,0,1])
        #print( mvp.dot([0,0,0,1]) )
        mvp_ = numpy.asfortranarray(mvp, dtype=numpy.float32)
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(mat_loc, 1, False, mvp_)
        gl.glBindTexture(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1)
        gl.glUniform1i( tex_loc, 0)


        gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_QUADS, 4, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, None)

        gl.glBindTexture(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2)
        #gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_QUADS, len(indices)-4, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 4*2)


        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

Let me apologize for how huge that example is, but OpenGL is not compact.

My question is: how do I invoke `gl.glDrawElements` such that it will draw the remaining quads from the `index_buffer` (which was built from `indices`) ?  All the examples I have seen use None in the pointer field.  This contrasts with webGL where you can pass `0` to start at the beginning of the elements, or `i*2` to start at the `i`th index.

To make that example run you'll need a bear64.png and flamingo64.gif.  Any old image should work, but you could try http://www.purplefrog.com/~thoth/wow/bear-64.gif .

Comment: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawRangeElements.xhtml I´m on the run to different activity but this may be your answer. Will look closer into it tomorrow. Good luck.

Comment: After experimenting with that call, I think that its start and end parameters bound the vertex indices referenced by the indices array (meaning `start <= indices[i] <= end`, with `i` in `[0..count)` ), allowing it to avoid loading the entire vertex buffer.  I suspect we need to figure out what to pass in to indices instead of None to accomplish my mission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the OpenGL 4 reference (glBindBuffer):

> While a non-zero buffer object is bound to the
>   GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER target, the indices parameter of
>   glDrawElements, glDrawElementsInstanced, glDrawElementsBaseVertex,
>   glDrawRangeElements, glDrawRangeElementsBaseVertex,
>   glMultiDrawElements, or glMultiDrawElementsBaseVertex is interpreted
>   as an offset within the buffer object measured in basic machine
>   units.

Thus you should enter an offset in "basic machine units". It is really start_index*index_type_size. In your case index_type is SHORT, SHORT size is 2.  The trick is that value has to be cast to a C void pointer like so:

```
gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_QUADS, len(indices)- start,
                  gl.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, ctypes.c_void_p(start*2)).
```

Comment: If I change `None` to `4*2` to try to make it start on the 4th short in the index array, it draws nothing.  It even fails if I use 0 instead of None: `gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_QUADS, 4, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0)`

Comment: Try forcing a c_void_ptr as last argument: gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_QUADS, 4, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, ctypes.c_void_ptr(start*size))

Comment: Almost.  The line that did work was `gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_QUADS, len(indices)- start, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, ctypes.c_void_p(start *2))`  Incorporate that code sample into your answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Awesome! I have actually never coded OpenGL in Python :-D